# Search for string in multi-level array of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, recursion, next.js

I'm trying to build a searchable menu of teams in Javascript/TypeScript - not sure how to do it.

Basically, I have a set of data laid out like this.

```
const data = [
    {
        'name': 'Alex A',
        'agentId': '1225',
     },
    {
        'name': 'Tammy',
        'agentId': '125',
        'team': [
            {
                'name': 'Alex B',
                'agentId': 249
            },
            {
                'name': 'Alexander C',
                'agentId': 148
            },
            {
                'name': 'Ed',
                'agentId': 382
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'Edward',
        'agentId': '594',
        'team': [
            {
                'name': 'Daniel',
                'agentId': 152
            },
            {
                'name': 'Alexis D',
                'agentId': 1900
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

When I search (i.e. Alex) so my new data set would be:

```
const data = [
    {
        'name': 'Alex A',
        'agentId': '1225',
     },
    {
        'name': 'Tammy',
        'agentId': '125',
        'team': [
            {
                'name': 'Alex B',
                'agentId': 249
            },
            {
                'name': 'Alexander C',
                'agentId': 148
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'Edward',
        'agentId': '594',
        'team': [
            {
                'name': 'Alexis D',
                'agentId': 1900
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I am more familiar with PHP so I would do something along the lines of:

```
$x = 0;
foreach($data as $row){
       if (strpos($row.name, 'alex')) {
            $newArray[$x] = $row;
           }

       foreach($row['team'] as $person) {
        if (strpos($person.name, 'alex')) {
           if(!isset($newArray[$x])) {
             $newArray[$x] = $row;
          }
             $newArray[$x]['team'][] = $person;
            }
        $x++;
    }

}
```

Been working with Typescript within the last few months, so this is the rabbit hole i'm going down, but I know it's not right.

```js
const searchName = "Alex";
const newArray = [];
if (searchName.length >= 3) {
  const filtered = data.forEach((user) => {
    const name = user.name.toLowerCase();
    if (name.indexOf(searchName.toLowerCase())) {
      newArray.push(user);
    }
    if (user.team) {
      const teamFiltered = user.team.forEach((member) => {
        if (member.name.indexOf(searchName.toLowerCase())) {
          newArray.push({
            name: user.name,
            agentId: user.agentId,
            team: member,
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First iterate over each array item and create a new `team` property (if it exists in the first place) with only `Alex`es in it.

```
const searchStr = 'Alex'.toLowerCase();
const filteredTeams = data.map(
  obj => !obj.team ? obj : ({
    // clone to avoid mutation
    ...obj,
    team: objteam.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr))
  })
);
```

Then apply another filter so that the top-level items only contain those with names that match, *or* whose `team` property is not empty.

```js
const data=[{name:"Alex A",agentId:"1225"},{name:"Tammy",agentId:"125",team:[{name:"Alex B",agentId:249},{name:"Alexander C",agentId:148},{name:"Ed",agentId:382}]},{name:"Edward",agentId:"594",team:[{name:"Daniel",agentId:152},{name:"Alexis D",agentId:1900}]}];
const searchStr = 'Alex'.toLowerCase();

const filteredTeams = data.map(
  obj => !obj.team ? obj : ({
    // clone to avoid mutation
    ...obj,
    team: obj.team.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr))
  })
);
const output = filteredTeams.filter(({ name, team }) => (
  name.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr) ||
  team.length && team.length > 0
));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @itsjustcarlos note this solution only supports a single nesting level. see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808182/633183) for a technique that handles any level of nesting.

Answer (score 2):

We can start by defining the type for your `data`. We will make sure our solution works for data **nested to any depth** -

```
type Agent = {
  name: string,
  agentId: number,
  team?: Array<Agent>
}

const data: Array<Agent> = [
    { name: 'Alex A', agentId: 1225 },
    { name: 'Tammy', agentId: 125, team: [
        { name: 'Alex B', agentId: 249 },
        { name: 'Alexander C', agentId: 148, team: [
            { name: "Alice D", agentId: 999 }
        ]},
        { name: 'Ed', agentId: 382 }
    ]},
    { name: 'Edward', agentId: 594, team: [
        { name: 'Daniel', agentId: 152 },
        { name: 'Alexis D', agentId: 1900 }
    ]}
]
```

Next we write `filter` as a **mutually recursive** function. This technique is excellent for processing tree-like data. We have two functions -

1. `many` that processes a list of elements
2. `one` that processes a single element

Using the tandem pair we can easily filter the data with minimal complexity -

```
function filter(arr: Array<Agent>, query: string): Array<Agent> {
  function many(ts: Array<Agent>): Array<Agent> {
    return ts.flatMap(one)
  }
  function one(t: Agent): Array<Agent> {
    const team = many(t.team ?? [])
    // include the node if the query matches
    // or if the node has matching children
    return t.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) >= 0 || team.length > 0
        ? [ { ...t, team } ]
        : []
  }
  return many(arr)
}

console.log(filter(data, "alex"))
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the demo below to verify the result in your own browser or on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&noEmitHelpers=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAgg5hAdsKBeKBvAUFKiCGAthAFxQDOwATgJaJwA0OU+CyAkgCZmICuhAIwhUmuYBCIB+MjCpV8IADzwkwAHxYAvliwBjAPaJKUTvmD4Zchcrbq0UANrNcGPEVJQA5DAA2EAB6wngwstlxkAIwATFEArFCaoriYbsRkngAqRIQgwaGq4VDRsSHiRGROyVUpBGlevgFQAEJ5rAXcUFEALACcCUnVNe7pDf74iJzCUADCrWEdEV0AHKUShBXOg8mutR4ARL40utAAInshbRwdPTcJm1UAuon326kengCinHPtZADMSyid0ezyqO2GXi+AHd8FRvhd5mRYj0uqtyo4Xi43ukTuMaBAfD8rpFYkDQVtwXVvH5-DRyFATkTgIUIj0AAxs4HJJ5YB46ABmvEQumANEMUH5NB84ioAApYVRLPIlCpkGoQgBHXjCEBkSi0egASiV1lVdmwuEFwtF4sI4xAsuA5BNKtsamNsCsrtUakwmyoEGAvCoiCgToAdPyfGYALL4MCywwQQ3MbSWoUisWhpOOmS2D2yZU2H1+qoGIwoMqEex2xAO4DhqtQSSSRwPFNVANBkNh8O7Rv6AAy+ihwmm+HIEFlhvDdEm-gA8vzZVqdYaoGp0JyAD7bsNrcN+ejAAAWG6gbMxzccKXDd+AaOrmigfK2UAqr65XeDodrDoVKbaHohjkPofiHvocCypK0rCLKpjmCEez4DSeyGoaQA) -

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'Alex A', agentId: 1225 },
    { name: 'Tammy', agentId: 125, team: [
        { name: 'Alex B', agentId: 249 },
        { name: 'Alexander C', agentId: 148, team: [
            { name: "Alice D", agentId: 999 }
        ]},
        { name: 'Ed', agentId: 382 }
    ]},
    { name: 'Edward', agentId: 594, team: [
        { name: 'Daniel', agentId: 152 },
        { name: 'Alexis D', agentId: 1900 }
    ]}
]

function filter(arr, query) {
    function many(ts) {
        return ts.flatMap(one)
    }
    function one(t) {
        const team = many(t.team ?? [])
        return t.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) >= 0 || team.length > 0
            ? [{ ...t, team }]
            : []
    }
    return many(arr)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(filter(data, "alex"), null, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Alex A",
    "agentId": 1225,
    "team": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Tammy",
    "agentId": 125,
    "team": [
      {
        "name": "Alex B",
        "agentId": 249,
        "team": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Alexander C",
        "agentId": 148,
        "team": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Edward",
    "agentId": 594,
    "team": [
      {
        "name": "Alexis D",
        "agentId": 1900,
        "team": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

An obvious improvement would be to make `filter` a higher-order funciton, much like `Array.prototype.filter`. Instead of a fixed `query: string` parameter, we can use a `func: (agent: Agent) => boolean)` parameter, allowing the caller to `filter` with much greater flexibility -

```
function filter(
  arr: Array<Agent>,
  func: (agent: Agent) => boolean // ✅ filtering function
): Array<Agent> {
  function many(ts: Array<Agent>): Array<Agent> {
    return ts.flatMap(one)
  }
  function one(t: Agent): Array<Agent> {
    const team = many(t.team ?? [])
    return func(t) || team.length > 0 // ✅ simplified
        ? [ { ...t, team } ]
        : []
  }
  return many(arr)
}
```

The caller can specify exactly how the data is filtered now. This will produce the same result as before -

```js
filter(data, agent =>
  agent.name.toLowerCase().indexOf("alex") >= 0
)
```

But maybe the caller wishes to filter using regex -

```js
filter(data, agent => /ed/i.test(agent.name))
```

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Tammy",
    "agentId": 125,
    "team": [
      {
        "name": "Ed",
        "agentId": 382,
        "team": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Edward",
    "agentId": 594,
    "team": []
  }
]
```

Or perhaps you want to filter by `agentId` -

```js
filter(data, agent => agent.agentId == 1900)
```

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Edward",
    "agentId": 594,
    "team": [
      {
        "name": "Alexis D",
        "agentId": 1900,
        "team": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can verify these examples on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&noEmitHelpers=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAgg5hAdsKBeKBvAUFKiCGAthAFxQDOwATgJaJwA0OU+CyAkgCZmICuhAIwhUmuYBCIB+MjCpV8IADzwkwAHxYAvliwBjAPaJKUTvmD4Zchcrbq0UANrNcGPEVJQA5DAA2EAB6wngwstlxkAIwATFEArFCaoriYbsRkngAqRIQgwaGq4VDRsSHiRGROyVUpBGlevgFQAEJ5rAXcUFEALACcCUnVNe7pDf74iJzCUADCrWEdEV0AHKUShBXOg8mutR4ARL40utAAInshbRwdPTcJm1UAuon326kengCinHPtZADMSyid0ezyqO2GXi+AHd8FRvhd5mRYj0uqtyo4Xi43ukTuMaBAfD8rpFYkDQVtwXVvH5-DRyFATkTgIUIj0AAxs4HJJ5YB46ABmvEQumANEMUH5NB84ioAApYVRLPIlCpkGoQoLhWR5bYZLYAJRoNRQAT6fR+cb6pXWVV2bC4TUisWIKCEcYgWXAcjWlW2NRW2BWX2qY325JUCDAXhUF1egB0-J8ZgAsvgwLLDBB9cxtA6hU7xZnPXrVAHZMqbCHMJsDEYUGVCPY3YgPcA4w2oJJJI4HtmqhGozGJfnPYaAD5jqANuN+ejAAAWUGNbMxnccKTjm+AaMbmigfK2UAqB65A+jLubHoV2e0ekM5HNEBn+jgssl0uEstM5gRqiN+WQONdnbfQABl9ChYRpnwcgIFlfU4zoSZ-AAeX5WU9nwGk9kNNR0DZfVs1rB8-GfV93xlL8zHwX9kH-AB6CBOHomh2wgSgdVUID3EIoj70fMi3ylSjvxogCUFQY1LjbaSuDQdBWQ5QigA).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function

```js
const filterFn = (data, search) => {
  let str = search.toLowerCase();
  return data.map((element) => {
    // map through the array items and treat the object of every iteration as element
    let newTeam;
    if (element.team) {
      // if the property team exists in element
      newTeam = element.team.filter(
        // loop through element.team
        (member) => member.name.toLowerCase().includes(str) 
          // return each object with the property 'name' contains 'str' to 'newTeam'
      );
    }
    if (element.team && newTeam.length > 0) {
      // if 'newTeam' it is not an empty array so it is full of objects that contains 'str' in their property 'name'
      return { ...element, team: newTeam }; 
       // so we return a copy of element updating the property 'team' with the value of 'newTeam'
    } else if (element.name.toLowerCase().includes(str)) {
      // else ('newTeam' is empty) if (the property 'name' of element contains 'str')
      return element; 
      // we return element
    }
  });
};
```

And call it this way passing it the array you want to filter and the lookup value:

```js
const filtredArray = filterFn(data,"alex")
```